Caching the Sieve of Erathosthenes
I have the following code which generates all the primes numbers below n
def sieve(n):
    # sieve of Erathosthenes to generate prime numbers
    sieve = [True]*(n//2)
    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2):
        if sieve[i//2]:
            sieve[i*i//2::i] = [False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return (2,) + tuple(2*i + 1 for i in range(1, n//2) if sieve[i])

How can I amend the code to make use of caching? I.e. when sieve(n) is ran it first checks to see if it's been ran already. If it has, and the current n is less than or equal to the cached m, it just looks up the cached result and slices where it needs to. If the current n is greater than the cached m, it generates any additional primes and then overwrites the cache.
Is this doable?
Edit: I'm aware of the @cache decorator from functools, but I don't think this answers my question, as this just considers if n == m or not; it doesn't consider if n < m or n > m

I disagree. The @cache decorator would just cache the input n, so if the next input was m!=n then the cache wouldn't be utilised

The sieve should be a global variable, not a local variable. Or it could be a mutable default parameter. Either way, all calls to sieve() would be able to use it as a cache.

BTW, don't use the same name for the function and variable, it's confusing.

As you said yourself (well, implicitly, when you dismissed @cache, rightly so), you don't really need a cache here. You just need to intialize a sieve once for all, and the reuse it. The "cache" is the sieve. It is explicit in the algorithm. Word "cache", and moreover decorators and other tricks like @cache, are used when adding implicitely a cache can accelerate an algorithm, that formally doesn't care about that. For example for infamous def fib(n): return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2). Here, if you implement a sieve, you don't need a cache, since you already have it: it is the sieve.

So just make it a global variable (don't let dogmas get in the way. Rules like "global are bad" are true, generally speaking. But, well, globals exist for a reason, and python did not rule them out by construction, because sometimes, they are justified. So saying "globals are bad" without even trying to remember why they are bad, and therefore when there can be exception to this rules is counter-productive). Besides, if you wan't to avoid globals (to avoid pollution of scope), you have other options to have lifetime of global without the scope: class, dedicated unit, or attribute of sieve

But well, "caching the sieve" means "caching the cache". The sieve is a cache.

if you turn the function into a class you can have a member hold the values without the need for a global.
